# Attributes in String

Tags: xcode, swift, textview, nsattributedstring

I'm working with text. I have some arrays of ranges of text attributes, but when I'm applying italic to text which already has bold attributes, my bold attributes disappearing. How can I apply my attributes text to become boldItalic in this case? Or I should find an intersection of my bold and italic ranges to apply boldItalic attributes?

For example I have "This is my text" and I want to get "**This *is m*y** text"

Sorry, for poor english.
This is part of my code

```
func attributedArticleText ()-> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:NSAttributedString(string: articleText))
    if let strong = attributes?.strong {
        for range in strong {
            attString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Bold", size: 12.0)!], range: range.range())
        }
    }
    if let italic = attributes?.italic {
        for range in italic {
            attString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIText-LightItalic", size: 12.0)!], range: range.range())
        }
    }
    if let underLined = attributes?.underline {
        for range in underLined {
            attString.addAttributes([NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: 1], range: range.range())
        }
    }
    if let cross = attributes?.cross {
        for range in cross {
            attString.addAttributes([NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: 1], range: range.range())
        }
    }
    return attString
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, if somebody interested

```
if let italic = attributes?.italic {
        for range in italic {
            attString.enumerateAttributesInRange(range.range(), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0), usingBlock: { (dict : [String : AnyObject], rangeNS : NSRange, _) -> Void in
                if let font = dict["NSFont"] as? UIFont {
                    let descriptor = font.fontDescriptor()
                    if descriptor.symbolicTraits == .TraitBold {
                        attString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIText-BoldItalic", size: 12.0)!], range: range.range())
                    } else {
                        attString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIText-LightItalic", size: 12.0)!], range: range.range())
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `NSObliquenessAttributeName` if your app is targeting iOS7.0 and above

```
let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text!)
attr.addAttribute(NSObliquenessAttributeName, value: 0.5, range: NSMakeRange(0, text!.characters.count))
```

In Your code, you are changing the same attribute twice `NSFontAttributeName`.

This is for `Bold`

```
attString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Bold", size: 12.0)!], range: range.range())
```

And this is for `LightItalic`

```
attString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIText-LightItalic", size: 12.0)!], range: range.range())
```

**Solution:** Font `SFUIText-LightItalic` do not support `Bold`. Try to merge both, check if your font support `SFUIDisplay-BoldItalic` or something like that as

```
attString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-BoldItalic", size: 12.0)!], range: range.range())
```

Comment: As I understood, you are saying that, when I'm adding new attributes, I'm not actually adding new, I'm changing already applied?

Comment: yeah, but its also depends upon the range you are passing, if range are same then the current attribute will reflect and the older one will lost

Comment: What you need is bold cum italic as far as i understood your problem, then you must select the appropriate font, Try something like `BoldItalic` if your font supports, as I can see you are using different font `SFUIDisplay` and `SFUIText` are different font

Comment: You can try using `SFUIText-BoldItalic`